How exactly is a WPF element along with its other visual objects rendered?
I am a novice to C# and WPF. So I am browsing through the dotnet wpf repository on github trying to find how a text selection/highlight made on text in a RichTextBox gets actually rendered onto the screen. So far I found many files, classes and interfaces that are highly interconnected, however I am still unable to exactly figure out where this rendering and its logic is located. Is it a function, an instantiation of an object, passing a message or something else that makes a highlight visible on screen ?
Is it somewhere inside : TextSelectionHighlightLayer.cs ?
I found the text selection changed event handler in TextBoxBase.cs as :
_textEditor.Selection.Changed += new EventHandler(OnSelectionChangedInternal);

Is it in Highlight.cs, HighlightLayer.cs ?
It also seems bizarre to me that I am not able to find it through inspecting RichTextBox.cs directly. For example SelectionBrush is the color of the selection rectangle that would be used when text highlighted, however I would suspect that the rendering system would use this variable when it actually shows the selection highlight but I simply am not able to figure where this property gets used (or if it used at all).

You may start reading here: WPF Graphics Rendering Overview. Complex controls like the RichTextBox are composed of a lot of other basic elements.

@Clemens okay, sure !

You have more than one question there. In terms of "brushes", WPF relies on "Styles" and  "StaticResources" to assign defaults to properties of a given "control type". One can override these default assignments by creating one's own resources that match the "key" of these (WPF) "system" resources. With one line, it's possible to make application wide property changes for a particular Control type. These styles and resources are typically created via XAML files.

The rendering engine does not check any variables. It does not know any controls (it only cares about Visuals). It operates at a lower level. It does not render the RichTextBox. It renders what the RichTextBox tells it to render. In this case the RichTextBox tells the engine to draw a rectangle with specific attributes at a specified position on screen. And it tells the engine to render a border (another rectangle) and some glyphs or other nested Visuals.

This is a bit like asking how gravity works. There are a dozen possible answers depending on how deep you want to get. Fundamentally, WPF always uses DirectX9 to draw pixels to the window. There's a very dense C++ library that you can study if you really want. Everything else is a layer above that, layer upon layer upon layer. How deep do you actually want to go? Too deep and you may never return. :) If you focus more on what you want to achieve rather than just "how does it work" there are many people here who can help I'm sure. But this is a hard question to answer abstractly.
